# Writing in the physical memory contiki

Tags: linux, file, contiki

I'm using Linux distribution contiki OS,,

I want to write info into file in the physical memory not logical ,,

I try this ex using CFS (Coffee contiki file system) and it work fine (write (cfs_write) and read (cfs_read)),, but i could not find where is the file store (the path) ,, 
then i found that it's store in the logical memory *_*,

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Coffee-filesystem-example

,,

Comment: Contiki is not Linux.

Comment: I mean instant contiki open using linux vm

Comment: instant contiki is ubuntu linux with some pre-installed packages. It is delivered as an image which can be started using a virtual machine software like VirtualBox or VMWare player.